# Wait for delay within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to add wait for delay in my stored procedure after deleting 5 records. `@rowstoremove = 5`. And I would like to execute this procedure through a job and would like to make sure how many records have been deleted within 1 hour or so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].DeleteRecords
    @rowstoremove int = 0,
    @executeOnce  char(1) = 'Y'
As
Begin
    Declare @err int, 
            @rowCount int,
            @rowsToDelete int

    -- Load records of lowest id for a given duplicate set into a temp table
    select  
        Min(iD) keptID, UserId, AccountId, AddressId 
    into    
        #tmpKept
    from 
        adm.useraccess
    group by 
        UserId, AccountId, AddressId
    order by 1

    select *
    into #tmpRemoved
    from adm.useraccess A
    where not exists (select keptID 
                      from #tmpKept T 
                      where T.keptID = A.ID) 

    select @rowsToDelete = count(*) 
    from #tmpRemoved 

    if @rowstoremove = 0 
       select @rowstoremove = @rowsToDelete

    if @executeOnce = 'Y' 
    begin
        select 
            'Job Starting at ' + convert(varchar(255), getdate()) + '. Deleting a total of ' + convert(varchar(255), @rowstoremove) + ' rows'   

        delete top (@rowstoremove) adm.useraccess   
        from adm.useraccess A, #tmpRemoved R
        where A.ID = R.ID

        set @rowCount  = @@ROWCOUNT

        select 'Duplicate rows removed: ' +  convert(varchar(255), @rowCount) +' on: (' + convert(varchar(255), getdate())  + ')'   

        return
    end

    if @executeOnce !='Y'
    begin
        select 'Job Starting at ' + convert(varchar(255), getdate()) + '. Deleting a total of ' +  convert(varchar(255), @rowsToDelete) +' rows in groups of ' + convert(varchar(255), @rowstoremove)   + ' rows at a time' 

        set @rowCount = 1

        -- Remove duplicate records
        while @rowCount > 0 
        begin
            delete top (@rowstoremove) adm.useraccess   
            from adm.useraccess A, #tmpRemoved R
            where A.ID = R.ID

            set @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

            select 'Duplicate rows removed: ' +  convert(varchar(255), @rowCount) +' on: (' + convert(varchar(255), getdate())  + ')'   
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: For `@executeOne` use BIT which works like 1 - true, 0 - false

Comment: I don't quite follow you.. you want to create a stored procedure that run for an hour? please don't do that!

Comment: if you want to delete five rows at a time, then sleep for 5 sec, you need to delete TOP 5, then WAITFOR DELAY, and loop until all the intended rows have been deleted.  Why you would want to do this is beyond me, but that is how you would do it.

Comment: This has to be the only time i have ever seen someone who wants to slow a proc down!  and i have been using SQL for 20 years now!!

Answer (score 1):

Use waitfor (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx):

```
WAITFOR 
{
    DELAY 'time_to_pass' 
  | TIME 'time_to_execute' 
  | [ ( receive_statement ) | ( get_conversation_group_statement ) ] 
    [ , TIMEOUT timeout ]
}
```